# How do I perform a Blogspot Mobile site auto-redirect?

Tags: redirect, mobile, blogger

Using the [DETECT MOBILE BROWSER javaScript](http://detectmobilebrowsers.com/), I wanted to redirect mobile users from my site [www.itsappleos.com](http://www.itsappleos.com) to the mobile version m.itsappleos.com.

The issue I have is how do I get URLs automatically redirected to their respective paths on the mobile site and not to the homepage Url?

That's like from [www.itsappleos.com/abc](http://www.itsappleos.com/abc) to m.itsappleos.com/abc automatically?

Comment: Does the javascript that you are using allow editing? If so, Can you share the portion of the code where you specified that www.example.com should redirect to m.example.com?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I found an easier solution using Cloudflare Mobile redirect since I have the main and subdomain pointing to Cloudflare.